# Search implementation with flexsearch.js

Tags: javascript, hugo, flexsearch

I am studying hugo by cloning my favorite site.

I’m trying to implement a search function using flexsearch.js engine.
The search engine works very well on its search page:

http://localhost:1313/search/

But when I try to search from navbar box input form or using the search form on the home page, the script opens the search page but without a search.

As a beginner on javascript I am sure there is an error in the script implementation at /assets/js/search.js

I know it’s not Hugo’s problem but can you tell me a possible solution to follow?

This is a project’s repo
https://github.com/antedoro/Arberia.git

Answer (score 0):

The theme as a dedicated JavaScript code, which detects text being entered in the search box of the search page, and displays matching results. It is located [at the end of this file](https://arberiatheme.netlify.app/js/en.search.7b7436b0743d12d8643faac89ec0527cdb40b57c990729ad8793895b23b7bc30.js).

The search box that is in the top bar does not have this JavaScript code, so nothing happens when you start to type text in this search box.